# how to install a specific version of node-red

Tags: node.js, node-red

I'm trying to install a specific version of `node-red v0.19.7`. 
I've  tried 
`npm install node-red@0.19.3` without anysuccess. 
does anybody has an idea how to do it?

thanks in advance !

Comment: there is no such version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red  `..., 0.20.0-beta.2, 0.19.5, 0.19.4, ...`

Comment: sorry meant 0.19.3

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio  any idea how to do it  ?

Comment: `npm install node-red@0.19.3 --save`  works on my box. I get 5 warnings (deprecated modules) and one bcrypt fallback, other than that it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the question,  here how I'm doing it now :

```
npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red@0.19.5
```